# Magento2: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of

Tags: magento2

I try install module via composer.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

I change in php.ini memory_limit to 1024M

Still the same issue.

Any solution?

Comment: From your OS Command Prompt, please post TEXT results of A) TOP and B) HTOP so we can see how much RAM you have available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to change memory limit to `2048M`- you have 1.5Gb in error log.
or try to use direct memory settings

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer require "vendor/package"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command for setting the memory limit as unlimited

php -d memory_limit=-1 composer require "vendorName/ModuleName"

Another way you can change memory_limit=-1 in php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Just give -1 as memory_limit value. The **composer** command in this case becomes the argument of **php** command, so you need to provide its absolute path. Or you can use the which command

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 $(which composer) require "vendor/package"
```